# VB.NET Detect memory manipuation?

Tags: vb.net

i'm working at the moment on an "anticheat" for a game (just for fun i'm not a programmer :D). So, i would like to do something to block players from manipulation / injecting memory to the game process (call of duty 4).

I've already tried to read something about, and all i have found on the internet is to create a CRC32 or to check the hex checksum.
Can someone help me to do this? Aren't there other methods ?

This is what I found:
 http://www.slavasoft.com/fastcrc/samples/vb_net_sample_checksum_crc32_file.htm
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?342839-VB-Net-CRC32-HashAlgorithm

Sorry for my bad english i'm italian and thanks you :D

Comment: This is very tricky, because A) you would have to identify code vs data memory allocations.  Game data will change all of the time; B) .NET does not provide native access to memory directly; C) I don't believe you can access memory of another process at all without running as part of the OS (e.g. as a driver).  I could be wrong about that; D) Call of Duty 4 might write to code blocks (for example, to prevent hacking... that was very common years ago when I was interested in the topic).

Comment: You could use ReadProcessMemory to access the memory but a checksum would be useless as the program changes data memory anyway in  normal functionalty and checking loaded dlls is pointless as a reasonable number of cheats can be preformed from just editing data memory.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to go down on reversing and antireversing. See here some techiniques http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/windows-anti-debug-reference.
I think it will be hard to do these things on a managed language. You will need full access to the memory and some assembly knowledge.

Comment: so ... made it with VB.net is something impossible so... can you just help me to build a crc32 function / hex checksum? And also i think is possible to get all the module related to a process with this function right? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682621(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: so ... What do you recommend?

Comment: I would recommend learning C and some Assembly before. Its very interesting field of study. But what you are trying to accomplish is no so easily done. But you cant do this kind of thing without becoming a programmer before, you must know how to code. Good luck on your journey.